# How to pass values through the post request to hide URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, http-post

I want to hide url , when i click on edit button .
I tried to use `@Html.ActionLink` for it , but i have result like this 
`http://localhost:57098/Home/Edit/1` and i need this result: `http://localhost:57098/Home/Edit`.
I tried also made it through the `input`, but when i click the input button - i have zero effect.
Please help me to find my mistake and make post request properly .
My Controller

```
    [Authorize]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
 IEnumerable<LPU> lpuv = kz.LPUs.Where(x => x.Code == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).ToList();
                return View(lpuv);

            }

            [Authorize]
            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Index(LPU lpusi)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Home" , new { ogrn = lpusi.M_NAMES });

            }

            [Authorize]
            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Edit(string ogrn)
            {
                var lpue = kz.LPUs.Where(x => x.C_OGRN.Contains(ogrn)).FirstOrDefault();
                return View(lpue);
            }
```

My View:

```
  @model IEnumerable<LpuList.Models.LPU>

  ...

 <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.M_NAMES)
            </th>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FAM_GV)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TEL)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FAX)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.E_MAIL)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.M_NAMES)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FAM_GV)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TEL)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FAX)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.E_MAIL)
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" formaction=@Url.Action("Index") formmethod="post">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Изменить", "Edit", new { ogrn = item.M_NAMES }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-large" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
...
```

Comment: refer this link:-http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/814/routing-aspnet-mvc

Comment: @Mr.Roshan my question is not about routing. I want to make post request , but it's not working, and i don't know why.

Comment: You want to hide url?? or your Post method not getting call

Comment: you'd don't appear to have a form tag, which will be why your submit doesn't work. A submit button will only submit a form if there's a form to submit! Why do you need to hide the ID from the URL though? It's just an ID, it's not sensitive data, and presumably the user already knows what they clicked on...

Comment: @Mr.Roshan I want to pass parameter through the post. And this will hide url.

Comment: @ADyson . I have the page like this http://localhost:57098/Home/Edit/1 . If user will change the url to .../Home/Edit/2 , he will see the information that not intended to him!

Comment: Oh dear...please understand that security by obscurity (i.e. hiding things) is **not** security! Things are hidden, but they're still there. You realise the user can just manipulate the POST request instead using the developer tools included in every browser? A little bit harder yes, but you can find out how to do it online quite quickly if you're interested. In fact a user needn't even use a browser to make the request, they could use a tool like PostMan instead to construct it, and get back the response.

Comment: The correct way to deal with this problem is that the "Edit" action method should first get the ID of the item being requested, and get the current User's identity, and then check that the user has permission to see that item. If they have permission, continue to display the data. If they don't have permission, display an error message. This is how all properly written websites and APIs are secured. Simply hoping the user does not find your URL or data values does not provide any real security at all, it simply delays the moment when the data breach occurs. Please change your design now.

Comment: ADyson is right. Your problem is not to hide the ID from the URL but to add in some back end security to your app. If UserA can only see ID1 then you need to store something to signify that in your database. That way if UserA tries to look at anything they shouldn't you can catch it in the controller (request) and redirect them to the relevant 'fail' page before they see anything they shouldn't. Having an ID in an edit URL is NOT an issue that needs to be addressed.

Comment: @ADyson It's better to make user check in controller , or write authorization filter?

Comment: It depends if the rule is generic or specific to the action method depending on the data requested. An authorisation filter is generally something to re-use across multiple actions, and generally asks the question "Can the user access this action method?". But in this case it sounds like the user may access the action method, but the question is "Is the user permitted to access the specific piece of data being requested?". In that case, IMO you'd be better to implement it within the action method itself, since the rule is specific to that piece of data and that particular situation.